# Reduction of accuracy - Bagging

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning, bagging

Bagging is an ensemble method which uses a parallel set of classifiers and then gives consensus output. Usually bagging improves the accuracy of a classification. But if there are situations in which the accuracy is reduced once the Bagging is applied(I personally have experienced this.), what could be the reasons for that. I am just asking this generally. I am not asking for a specific situation.